# Data Binding Data Formatting Issue

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have a AutoCompleteBox bound to the datasource.  DataSource contains two string
 properties. I have defined ItemTemplate for AutoCompleteBox.

I want second property to come closed in brackets e.g. Property1 Data (Property2 Data)
I will have to define StringFormat during Binding.

I am totally unaware of format. Can anyone tell me the format.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is examples.

A simple way to use StringFormat in the binding.

Output: (0)

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Videos.Count, StringFormat='({0})', FallbackValue='(0)'}" />
```

Using `<Run>` tags you can also build complex values.

Output: Distance: 200km

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Distance: " />
    <Run Text="{Binding VideoDistance, StringFormat='\{0:G\}'}" />
</TextBlock>
```

If you use the second example, you must just add another `<Run>` tag for the next value.

You can also use a horizontal `StackPanel` to show multiple values.

Output: Start Distance: 200km

```
<!--START DISTANCE MIN-->
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Start Distance:" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding StartDistanceMinStr, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin... I have tried both the examples, both are working as expected.
Can you give an example using stackPanel?